# Blender 2.83 doesn't load ".blend" file on my Ubuntu computer

Tags: startup-file

I use Blender 2.83 on Ubuntu 20.04. When i double click on a ".blend" file, Blender doesn't load my project but opens the default Startup file. I did use Blender 2.82 with the same operating system and the same computer whithout any problem. Is it a bug?

Comment: Hi! Can you provide the exact steps you did to install? That will help us reproduce your error.

Comment: Did you update the default app to use for blend files in the os when you upgraded?

Comment: I installed Blender 2.82 first and Ubuntu apps automatically updates Blender for me. It's installed as Snap app

Answer (score 0):

I fix it. I had this problem because Blender has been updated automatically to 2.83. I just uninstall and reinstall it. It works fine now. Sorry for this question.